# How can I add a context menu extension to Azure DevOps 2019 Wiki More drop-down

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

I want to add a menu option to the Azure DevOps 2019 Wiki More drop-down list.  I looked in the Microsoft docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/reference/targets/overview?view=azure-devops) but I don't see any contributions/targets for the wiki context menu.  Is anyone aware of what values to provide in the vss-extension.json in order to have a context menu item appear there?

[image: 'More' context menu in the Azure DevOps 2019 wiki page]

Answer (score 1):

For now we can't insert your own button/ menu option to Azure DevOps Wiki More drop-down just as document described.

You could submit uservoice  to our [Develop Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea) as a feature request.

As a workaround,  you could put your content menu extension as a hub in targetable hub groups such as Azure Board/Work `ms.vss-work-web.work-hub-group`.